# MySQL Workbench: No Password Is Set For This Account

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

In MySQL Workbench I get an alert on every accounts page that there is no password set but I do have a password set.

[image]

Is this referring to something else or is it a bug of some sort?

(I am using latest version of MariaDB if that makes any difference)

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB are you running?  The latest versions have changes to password authentication that could be confusing Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it could be that it has to do with the MariaDB. Have you tried with a MySQL server instead. MySQL Workbench is developed for and tested with only MySQL servers.